# Match query returns nothing

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to search text inside fields.

I tried to fix my problem from [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

One of my index contains items which structure is the following:

```
{
    url: "https://exampleurl.com"
    username: "some_username"
}
```

Here is my querys:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match":  {
        "query": keyword,
        "type": "phrase",
        "fields": [ "username", "url" ]
    }

}
```

Also bool query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "multi_match":  {
                 "query": keyword,
                 "type": "phrase",
                 "fields": [ "username", "url" ]
            }
        },
    }
}
```

```
"query": {
"bool": {  
    "must": [{
        "match": {
            "username": keyword,
        }
     }, {
        "match": {
            "url": keyword
        }
    }]
}
}
```

But result is a empty array

Comment: Please share the index definition. Index fields type you have defined and also the exact quey you are trying to search so that we can help.

Comment: @dassum I'v provided example of my index fields and also querys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the below query.

1. Create Index

```
    PUT test
    {
        "settings" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1
        },
        "mappings" : {
            "properties" : {
                "url" : { "type" : "text" },
                "username" : { "type" : "text" }

            }
        }
    }
```

2. Insert Document

```
    PUT test/_doc/1
    {
        "url" : "https://exampleurl.com",
        "username" : "Arjun Das"    
    }
```

3. Search

```
    GET test/_search
    {
    "query": {
        "multi_match":  {
            "query": "http",
            "type": "best_fields",
            "fields": [ "username", "url" ],
            "fuzziness":"2"

        }
    }
    }
```